# Could anyone explain to me how the products of nuclear fusion/fission are predicted?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, fusion

I have an idea of how quantum mechanics work, but I know too little to understand which products are a result of certain reactions like bombarding a certain atom with neutrons or just by natural decay. How can they be predicted?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It takes heavy duty nuclear physics to actually calculate the decay behavior of a nucleus; for the vast majority of us who aren't nuclear physicists, we just [look it up](https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html).